# How can I check if a flight has landed or is delayed when I don't know the flight number but know some facts?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, flight-status

Say for instance that I know just information such as:

- Country from which flight departed (but maybe not city)
- Country in which airline is based (but maybe not name of airline)
- Airport flight will arrive at
- Date on which flight ought to arrive

Are there flight trackers that can take info such as this and narrow it down to just the flights which fit? (Basically a database query)

If not with this specific info, then which minimal info?

Comment: Do you know the time of arrival or just the date?

Comment: In this case just the date, but trying to keep the question generic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that using a website like flightstats (http://www.flightstats.com/go/Home/home.do) will do the job. You can search by route, flight or airport. If that does not work, checking the arrival airport's website normally lists all arrivals on the date of your choice as well as where they arrive from and what airline. That would probably do the trick if you don't mind looking around for a bit.
This of course is assuming you are trying to do this as a one time type thing just to see when for example your friend will be arriving...

Comment: Yes it would be for a one time thing now and then.

Answer (score 1):

Schiphol, the Amsterdam Airport, publishes all arrivals, as well as all departures, on the [text service](http://teletekst-data.nos.nl/webtekst?p=758-1) of the Dutch public television.
A quick search shows that [London Heathrow](http://www.heathrowairport.com/flight-information/live-flight-arrivals) also has a list of arrivals.
Which makes me think that you might be able to find that information for almost all airports, if maybe not all in English.

All you need is the name of the arrival airport and the departure city, to make a guess which plane they might be on.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other tricks:

1. [flightaware](http://flightaware.com) is a great service to track flights. If you are not sure of the flight number, just enter the departure location and the arrival, and it will give you a listing of all flights, their times, and their current status. If the flight is airborne, you may also be able to track it.
2. Another option is to enter a query into Google for the cities, such as "flights between switzerland and italy" and it will show all available flights; basically a flight schedule. If you know the day of week, you can narrow down the choices and once you click on a flight number, it will tell you the current status in the search results (delayed, en-route landed, etc.)
3. If you know the destination airport, you can find out the flights landing; and then work your way back given the day of week to the date of your flight. Once you get the flight number - punch it into a search engine like flightaware to get historic time information.

The above have yet to fail me, but there is another option. It is a bit of a long shot, but I am entering it here because its not one that's often mentioned.

4. [wolframalpha](https://wolframalpha.com) is a "knowledge engine". You can enter a query like [flights above new york](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=flights+above+new+york) and it will give you some very detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call the air port where you are, and ask if they can tell you if there is any way for them to see if the plane that you are looking for has landed or delayed!

Comment: I sometimes see advice like "call the airport" or "call the airlines". Does that actually work? In  my experience you simply talk to a robot for a bit, followed by an enormous wait and then, if you are lucky, you get to talk to a real human being in distant call center with limited language abilities who has no idea what you are talking about, and can only follow fixed written scripts.